# Using keystoneJS with another database

Tags: mongodb, google-cloud-datastore, keystonejs

Currently I need to create admin ui, using google cloud datastore as user storage, and google functions as controllers. 
I found the Keystone JS CMS platform, which uses mongoDB for storing user data, so I am looking for the chance to use it with google cloud datastore.

Is it possible to create some driver that will redirect all the keystone db requests not to mongodb, but in Google Datastore?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The core of Keystone is built on top of Mongo (and Mongoose) functions and code. At the moment, there isn't another way to use Keystone with another database type or provider. See [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/keystonejs/keystone/issues/2323) for some more information that may be of use.

Comment: What id redirect the keystone db requests to more than one mongodb, like a load balancer? Is it possible?